# Formulario con React TS no funciona Astro

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formularios

Estoy creando un formulario de registro utilizando react y typescript. El error es que cuando hago el onClick en el button con el toggleVariant no funciona en la pagina, pero tampoco me tira ningun error. No se si es un error con el valor de variant o con la funcion toggleVariant.

Me seria muy util que me ayudaran y me expliquen cual es el error que cometi.
Muchas gracias

Este es el código:

```
    'use client'

import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { useForm, type FieldValues, type SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form'
import { BsGoogle, BsFacebook } from 'react-icons/bs'

import Input from '../../components/Input/Input'
import Button from '../../components/Button'
import AuthSocialButton from './AuthSocialButton'

type Variant = 'LOGIN' | 'REGISTER'

const AuthForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [variant, setVariant] = useState<Variant>('LOGIN')
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    const toggleVariant = useCallback(() => {
        if (variant === 'LOGIN') {
            setVariant('REGISTER')
        }
        if (variant === 'REGISTER') {
            setVariant('LOGIN')
        }
    }, [variant])

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<FieldValues>({
        defaultValues: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
        },
    })

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = data => {
        setIsLoading(true)

        if (variant === 'REGISTER') {
            // Handle registration logic here
        } else {
            // Handle login logic here
        }
    }

    const socialAction = (action: string) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
    }

    return (
        <div className='mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md'>
            <div className='bg-white px-4 py-8 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10'>
                <form className='space-y-6' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    {variant === 'REGISTER' && (
                        <Input
                            label='Name'
                            id='name'
                            register={register}
                            errors={errors}
                            disabled={isLoading}
                        />
                    )}
                    <Input
                        label='Email address'
                        id='email'
                        type='email'
                        register={register}
                        errors={errors}
                        disabled={isLoading}
                    />
                    <Input
                        label='Password'
                        id='password'
                        type='password'
                        register={register}
                        errors={errors}
                        disabled={isLoading}
                    />
                    <div>
                        <Button disabled={isLoading} fullWidth type='submit'>
                            {variant === 'LOGIN' ? 'Sign in' : 'Register'}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div className='mt-6'>
                    <div className='relative'>
                        <div className='absolute inset-0 flex items-center'>
                            <div className='w-full border-t border-gray-300'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='relative flex justify-center text-sm'>
                            <span className='bg-white px-2 text-gray-500'>
                                Or continue with
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='mt-6 flex gap-2'>
                        <AuthSocialButton
                            icon={BsGoogle}
                            onClick={() => socialAction('google')}
                        />
                        <AuthSocialButton
                            icon={BsFacebook}
                            onClick={() => socialAction('facebook')}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className='flex gap-2 justify-center text-sm mt-6 px-2 text-gray-500'>
                        <div>
                            {variant === 'LOGIN'
                                ? 'New to Messenger?'
                                : 'Already have an account?'}
                        </div>
                        <button className='underline text-sm' onClick={toggleVariant}>
                            {variant === 'LOGIN' ? 'Create an account' : 'Log in'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AuthForm
```

El formulario esta creado con astro y uso React y typescript. El mismo es un clon del de messenger. Esta hecho solo con fines de aprendizaje.

Comment: Entonces al invocar al método `toggleVariant` cuyo valor inicial es `LOGIN` se debe cambiar el valor a `REGISTER` y con esto se debería ver el input `name`, ¿Es esto lo que no funciona?

Comment: @g.4 Exactamente, ese es el error. Al hacer el onClick en el button no se ejecuta el cambio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trate de emular el problema en `nextjs` y sucede lo mismo que en `Astro`.

Comparto mis notas esperando que sean de ayuda.

---

Parece que no se puede inyectar `JSX.Element/ReactNode` dentro de una etiqueta tipo `flow content` como lo es `form`:

```
//patron invalido en use client nextjs
<form>
  {variant === 'REGISTER' && (
            <Input
                label='Name'
                id='name'
                register={register}
                errors={errors}
                disabled={isLoading}
             />
  )}
</form>
```

No pude encontrar documentación al respecto, lo mas parecido en nextjs parece ser un error de [tipo hydration](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error), el árbol de react pre-renderizado en servidor es diferente del árbol renderizado en el primer render en cliente, que es parecido a lo que se expone en esta pregunta.

Se puede proponer una mejora a la composición de los componentes, por ejemplo en este caso se podría aplciar `separation of concerns` y generar dos componentes uno con el `form Login` y otro con el `form Register`, es mucho mas `declarativo` que inyectar `statements` y generar contenido dinámico en un solo `form`:

```
type Variant = 'LOGIN' | 'REGISTER'
//pseudo-codigo de componente AuthForm
const FormBug = () => {
    const [variant, setVariant] = useState<Variant>('LOGIN');

    const toggleVariant = () => {
        if (variant === 'LOGIN') {
            setVariant('REGISTER')
        }
        if (variant === 'REGISTER') {
            setVariant('LOGIN')
        }
    }

    function handleSubmit(){

    }
       
    console.log('variant', variant);

    return (
        <>
        {   
            (variant === 'LOGIN') ? <FormLogin handler={toggleVariant}/> : <FormRegister handler={toggleVariant}/>
        }
        </>
    );
}


function FormLogin({ handler } : { handler: ()=> void }){
  return (
        <form>
            <div>Hello from lOGIN FORM</div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button className='underline text-sm' onClick={handler}>
            Go to Register form
            </button>
        </form>
        
    ) 
}

function FormRegister({ handler } : { handler: ()=> void }){
    return (
        <form>
            <div>Hello from REGISTER FORM</div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button className='underline text-sm' onClick={handler}>
                Go to Login form
            </button>
        </form>
        
    ) 
  }
```